# Installing additional R Package on Azure ML

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

I am doing the following steps to install R Hash_2.2.6.zip package on to Azure ML

1. Upload the .zip file as a dataset
2. Create a new experiment and Add "Execute R Script" to experiment
3. Drag and drop .zip file dataset to experiment.
4. Connect the Dataset in step3 to "Execute R Script" of step2
5. Run the experiment to install the package

However I am getting this error: `zip file src/hash_2.2.6.zip not found`

Just so that its very clear, I am following steps mentioned in this article: http://blogs.technet.com/b/saketbi/archive/2014/08/20/microsoft-azure-ml-amp-r-language-extensibility.aspx.

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install a package this way, you have to create a .zip of a .zip. The outer layer of packaging will get unzipped into the src/ folder when the dataset is passed in to the module, and you'll be able to install the inner package from there.