# Installing additional R package (ImputeTS R Package) in Azure ML

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service, imputets

I referred the below stack overflow query regarding installing additional R package in Azure ML. However I'am getting the error

Trail 1 : Installing miniCRAN package for windows (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imputeTS/index.html)

Trail 2:  Installing ImputeTS package for windows (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/index.html)

**I double zipped and tried as per the below stack overflow query question. But, still facing the same issue**

R version i'm using : `CRAN 3.1.0`

I need to use the `package ImputeTS.`

**Stack overflow query link :**
[Installing additional R Package on Azure ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568624/installing-additional-r-package-on-azure-ml)

**Error 1:**

```
    Error 0063: The following error occurred during evaluation of R script:

    ---------- Start of error message from R ----------

    zip file 'src/miniCRAN.zip' not found
```

**Error 2:**

```
     Error 0063: The following error occurred during evaluation of R script:

     ---------- Start of error message from R ----------

     zip file 'src/imputeTS.zip' not found
```

**R script :**

```
JCI_CO2  <- maml.mapInputPort(1)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

#install.packages("src/imputeTS.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
#(success <- library("imputeTS", lib.loc = ".", logical.return = TRUE, verbose = TRUE))

 #library(imputeTS)
 #library(imputeTS,lib.loc = ".")


install.packages("src/miniCRAN.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
(success <- library("miniCRAN", lib.loc = ".", logical.return = TRUE, verbose = TRUE))

library(miniCRAN)
library(miniCRAN,lib.loc = ".")

library(imputeTS)

dt2 <- JCI_CO2 %>%
  mutate(Date.Time = mdy_hm(Date.Time)) %>%
  filter(Date.Time %in% seq(min(Date.Time), max(Date.Time), by = "15 min")) %>%
  complete(Date.Time = seq(min(Date.Time), max(Date.Time), by = "15 min")) %>%
  mutate(RA.CO2 = na.interpolation(RA.CO2)) %>%
  arrange(desc(Date.Time))


  JCI_CO2 <- data.frame(dt2)

  maml.mapOutputPort("JCI_CO2");
```

**Note :** *All the rest of the packages in the code i.e dplyr, tidyr, lubridate are already part of the azure ml R package. **Except ImputeTS which i am trying to install.***

Answer (score 0):

When facing issues with the Execute R or Python Script modules (actually all modules, but more helpful for these), selecting the module will show a View Output Log link in the properties pane on the right hand side. This will show the stdout + stderr of the module, which is more verbose than the final parsed error message in the window.

Specifically for diagnosing "path does not exist" issues like this, attaching a Zip file to the Zip input port of Exec R/Py will actually dump the full listing of what was unzipped to where within the context of the R/Python interpreter. Please use that to identify why the paths you're providing aren't resolving as you'd expect.